# C# how to create object in 1st Form from 2nd Form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm not clear how to create an object *(Attribute: panel with label and text box inside)* in the 1st Form (Main form) from 2nd Form.

1. 1st Form has a panel in which *Attribute* should be created.
2. 1st Form also has a *Button* which opens the 2nd Form.
3. 2nd Form takes roles of creation & configuration of *Attribute*
4. 2nd Form has *Button*-"Create". When clicked it should create an attribute in the 1st Form and insert it into *Panel of Attributes*.

Could you please provide me with some examples how It would be possible to perform such action?

[image: Main Form]
[image: 2nd Form]

Answer (score 1):

Why not let `Form1` create the control for *itself*?

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {

     public void CreateMyControl() {
       Panel attrPanel = new Panel() {
         Parent = this,
         Size = new Size(100, 60),   //TODO: Put the right value here
         Location = new Point(0, 0), //TODO: Put the right value here 
       };  

       new Label() {
         Parent   = attrPanel,         
         Text     = "I'm the Label", //TODO: Put the right value here
         Location = new Point(4, 4)  //TODO: Put the right value here
       };

       new TextBox() {
         Parent   = attrPanel, 
         Text     = "I'm the TextBox", //TODO: Put the right value here
         Location = new Point(4, 34)   //TODO: Put the right value here
       }    
    }

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // We create Form2 instance and pass current Form1 instance to it    
      Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);

      form2.ShowDialog(); // Or Show
    }
```

Having done with `Form1`, let's pass `Form1` to via constructor

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
  ...

  public Form1 ParentForm {get;} = null;

  public Form2() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public Form2(Form1 parentForm) : this() {
    ParentForm = parentForm;
  }

  private void btnCreateControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // If we have parent form, create some controls on it
    if (ParentForm != null)
      ParentForm.CreateMyControl(); 
  }
```

Comment: Or `.ShowDialog(this)`, then `((Form1)this.Owner).CreateMyControl();`, maybe passing some parameters, which seems what's the OP is after.